# Controlling emit values from Flux generate for sequential task execution

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm writing a simple orchestration framework using reactor framework which executes tasks sequentially, and the next task to execute is dependent on the result from previous tasks. I might have multiple paths to choose from based on the outcome of previous tasks. Earlier, I wrote a similar framework based on a static DAG where I passed as list of tasks as iterables and used `Flux.fromIterable(taskList)`. However, this does not give me the flexibility to go dynamic because of the static array publisher.

I'm looking for alternate approaches like `do(){}while(condition)` to solve for DAG traversal and task decision and I came up with `Flux.generate()`. I evaluate the next step in generate method and pass the next task downstream. The problem I'm facing now is, `Flux.generate` does not wait for downstream to complete, but pushes until the condition is set to invalid. And by the time task 1 gets executed, task 2 would have been pushed `n` times, which is not the expected behavior.

Can someone please point me towards the right direction?

Thanks.

First iteration using List of tasks (static DAG)

```
Flux.fromIterable(taskList)
        .publishOn(this.factory.getSharedSchedulerPool())
        .concatMap(
            reactiveTask -> {
              log.info("Running task =>{}", reactiveTask.getTaskName());
              return reactiveTask
                  .run(ctx);
            })
        // Evaluates status from previous task and terminates stream or continues.
        .takeWhile(context -> evaluateStatus(context))
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> buildResponse(ctx, throwable))
        .doOnCancel(() -> log.info("Task cancelled"))
        .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("Completed flow"))
        .subscribe();
```

Attempt to dynamic dag

```
Flux.generate(
            (SynchronousSink<ReactiveTask<OrchestrationContext>> synchronousSink) -> {
              ReactiveTask<OrchestrationContext> task = null;
              if (ctx.getLastExecutedStep() == null) {
                // first task;
                task = getFirstTaskFromDAG();
              } else {
                task = deriveNextStep(ctx.getLastExecutedStep(), ctx.getDecisionData());
                   
              }
              if (task.getName.equals("END")) {
                synchronousSink.complete();
              }
              synchronousSink.next(task);
            })
        .publishOn(this.factory.getSharedSchedulerPool())
        .doOnNext(orchestrationContextReactiveTask -> log.info("On next => {}", 
          orchestrationContextReactiveTask.getTaskName()))
        .concatMap(
            reactiveTask -> {
              log.info("Running task =>{}", reactiveTask.getTaskName());
              return reactiveTask
                  .run(ctx);                  
            })
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> buildResponse(ctx, throwable))
        .takeUntil(context -> evaluateStatus(context, tasks))
        .doOnCancel(() -> log.info("Task cancelled"))
        .doOnComplete(() -> log.info("Completed flow")).subscribe();
```

The problem in above approach is, while task 1 is executing, the `onNext()` subscriber prints many time because `generate` is publishing. I want the generate method to wait on results from previous task and submit new task. In non-reactive world, this can be achieve through simple while() loop.

Each Task will perform the following action.

```
public class ResponseTask extends AbstractBaseTask {
  private TaskDefinition taskDefinition;
  final String taskName;


  public ResponseTask(
      StateManager stateManager,
      ThreadFactory factory,
    ) {    
    this.taskDefinition = taskDefinition;
    this.taskName = taskName;
  }

   public Mono<String> transform(OrchestrationContext context) {
    Any masterPayload = Any.wrap(context.getIngestionPayload());
    return Mono.fromCallable(() -> stateManager.doTransformation(context, masterPayload);
  }

  
  public Mono<OrchestrationContext> execute(OrchestrationContext context, String payload) {
    log.info("Executing sleep for task=>{}", context.getLastExecutedStep());
    return Mono.delay(Duration.ofSeconds(1), factory.getSharedSchedulerPool())
        .then(Mono.just(context));
  }

  public Mono<OrchestrationContext> run(OrchestrationContext context) {
log.info("Executing task:{}. Last executed:{}", taskName, context.getLastExecutedStep());
  return transform(context)
         .doOnNext((result) -> log.info("Transformation complete for task=?{}", taskName);)
         .flatMap(payload -> {
             return execute(context, payload);
         }).onErrorResume(throwable -> {
             context.setStatus(FAILED);
             return Mono.just(context);
         }); 
}

}
```

**EDIT - From @Ikatiforis 's recommendation - I got the following output**

```
Here's the output from my side.

2021-12-02 09:58:14,643 INFO  (reactive_shared_pool) [ReactiveEngine lambda$doOrchestration$5:98] On next => Task1 
2021-12-02 09:58:14,644 INFO  (reactive_shared_pool) [ReactiveEngine lambda$doOrchestration$6:101] Running task =>Task1 
2021-12-02 09:58:14,644 INFO  (reactive_shared_pool) [AbstractBaseTask run:75] Executing task:Task1. Last executed:Task1 
2021-12-02 09:58:14,658 INFO  (reactive_shared_pool) [ReactiveEngine lambda$doOrchestration$5:98] On next => Task2 
2021-12-02 09:58:14,659 INFO  (reactive_shared_pool) [AbstractBaseTask lambda$run$0:83] Transformation complete for task=?Task1 
2021-12-02 09:58:14,659 INFO  (reactive_shared_pool) [ResponseTask execute:41] Executing sleep for task=>Task1 
2021-12-02 09:58:15,661 INFO  (reactive_shared_pool) [AbstractBaseTask lambda$run$4:106] Success for task=>Task1 
2021-12-02 09:58:15,663 INFO  (reactive_shared_pool) 
[ReactiveEngine lambda$doOrchestration$6:101] Running task =>Task2 
2021-12-02 09:58:15,811 INFO  (cassandra-nio-worker-8) [AbstractBaseTask run:75] Executing task:Task2. Last executed:Task2 
2021-12-02 09:58:15,811 INFO  (reactive_shared_pool) [ReactiveEngine lambda$doOrchestration$5:98] On next => Task2 
2021-12-02 09:58:15,812 INFO  (reactive_shared_pool) [AbstractBaseTask lambda$run$0:83] Transformation complete for task=?Task2 
2021-12-02 09:58:15,812 INFO  (reactive_shared_pool) [ResponseTask execute:41] Executing sleep for task=>Task2 
2021-12-02 09:58:15,837 INFO  (centaurus_reactive_shared_pool) [ReactiveEngine lambda$doOrchestration$9:113] Completed flow
```

I see couple of problems here --

```
The sequence of execution is 
 1. Task does transformations ( runs on Mono.fromCallable)
 2. Task induces a delay - Mono.fromDelay()
 3. Task completes execution. After this, generate method should evaluate the context and pass on the next task to be executed.

What I see from the output is:
 1. Task 1 starts the transformations - Runs on Mono.fromCallable.
 2. Task 2 doOnNext is reported - which means the stream already got this task.
 3. Task 1 completes.
 4. Task 2 starts and executes delay -> the stream does not wait for response from task 2 but completes the flow.
```

Comment: is the status in context updated earlier than the task completion? which could explain why the last task seems to be cut short (due to `takeUntil` perhaps?). why use `takeUntil` if you need to process all the tasks and their result btw? it would seem classic completion would suffice...

Comment: @SimonBaslé status is updated on error from tasks or logical failure. So it should wait for completion of said task as it is chained. takeUntil takes in a method which basically looks at this status flag, a binary flag, and terminates the flow. We do not need to continue if the logical output is false. So classic completion is not an option.

Comment: @SimonBaslé Also in this case,i modified the code to Ikatiforis 's suggestion -- the prefetch is making the stream execute the same task twice where as my expected behaviour is - generate one task -> wait until it completes -> evaluate status and next step -> pass down the task. ( This is the function of Flux.generate )

Answer (score 1):

> The problem in above approach is, while task 1 is executing, the
> onNext() subscriber prints many time because generate is publishing.

This is happening because `concatMap` requests a number of items upfront(32 by default) instead of requesting elements one by one. If you really need to request one element at the time you can use [`concatMap(Function<? super T,? extends Publisher<? extends V>> mapper,int prefetch)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#concatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-) variant method and provide the `prefetch` value like this:

```java
.concatMap(reactiveTask -> {
              log.info("Running task =>{}", reactiveTask.getTaskName());
              return reactiveTask.run(ctx);                  
            }, 1)
```

**Edit**

There is also a `publishOn` method which takes a `prefetch` value. Take a look at the following Fibonacci generator sample and let me know if it works as you expect:

```
generateFibonacci(100)
    .publishOn(boundedElasticScheduler, 1)
    .doOnNext(number -> log.info("On next => {}", number))
    .concatMap(number -> {
      log.info("Running task => {}", number);
      return task(number).doOnNext(num -> log.info("Task completed => {}", num));
    }, 1)
    .takeWhile(context -> context < 3)
    .subscribe();
```

```java
  public Flux<Integer> generateFibonacci(int limit) {
    return Flux.generate(
        () -> new FibonacciState(0, 1),
        (state, sink) -> {
          log.info("Generating number: " + state);
          sink.next(state.getFormer());
          if (state.getLatter() > limit) {
            sink.complete();
          }
          int temp = state.getFormer();
          state.setFormer(state.getLatter());
          state.setLatter(temp + state.getLatter());
          return state;
        });
  }
```

Here is the output:

```
2021-12-02 10:47:51,990  INFO main c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Generating number: FibonacciState(former=0, latter=1)
2021-12-02 10:47:51,993  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - On next => 0
2021-12-02 10:47:51,996  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Running task => 0
2021-12-02 10:47:54,035  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Task completed => 0
2021-12-02 10:47:54,035  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Generating number: FibonacciState(former=1, latter=1)
2021-12-02 10:47:54,036  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - On next => 1
2021-12-02 10:47:54,036  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Running task => 1
2021-12-02 10:47:56,036  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Task completed => 1
2021-12-02 10:47:56,036  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Generating number: FibonacciState(former=1, latter=2)
2021-12-02 10:47:56,036  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - On next => 1
2021-12-02 10:47:56,036  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Running task => 1
2021-12-02 10:47:58,036  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Task completed => 1
2021-12-02 10:47:58,036  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Generating number: FibonacciState(former=2, latter=3)
2021-12-02 10:47:58,036  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - On next => 2
2021-12-02 10:47:58,036  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Running task => 2
2021-12-02 10:48:00,036  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Task completed => 2
2021-12-02 10:48:00,037  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Generating number: FibonacciState(former=3, latter=5)
2021-12-02 10:48:00,037  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - On next => 3
2021-12-02 10:48:00,037  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Running task => 3
2021-12-02 10:48:02,037  INFO pool-1-thread-1 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Task completed => 3
2021-12-02 10:52:07,877  INFO pool-1-thread-2 c.u.p.p.s.c.Test - Completed flow
```

**Edit 04122021**

You stated:

> I'm trying to simulate HTTP / blocking calls. Hence the Mono.delay.

`Mono#Delay` is not the appropriate method to simulate a blocking call. The delay is introduced through the parallel scheduler and as a result, it does not wait for the task to complete. You can simulate a blocking call like this:

```java
  public String get() throws IOException {
    HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments").openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    try(InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream()) {
      return new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
  }
```

Note that as an alternative you could use `.limitRate(1)` operator instead of the `prefetch` parameter.

Comment: @Ikatiforis I added this change but now, flux is signaling ```onComplete``` before Task 2 gets done with execution. Also, the decision of which task to execute should be decided after task 1 executes, but here, task 2 is already prefetch and is ready. How do I wait, re-evaluate and generate the right task in ```Flux.generate``` ?

Comment: @PavanKumar edit made

Comment: @ikatiforis I updated the main thread with my output and my behavior is different from yours. I have some ```Mono.fromCallable``` and delay calls.

Comment: @PavanKumar so, update your answer to include all of your functionality.

Comment: @ikatiforis updated task information as well.

Comment: @PavanKumar there are messages in your logs that can not be found in your code snippet. It's very difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239794/discussion-between-pavan-kumar-and-lkatiforis).

Comment: @PavanKumar edit made

Comment: Still the same effect. limitRate / prefetch is doing what it says and pulls another item. the expected behavior is, flux should only generate after the downstream has completed executions. @SimonBaslé this is what we have tried. is there a provision with reactor for the expected behavior?